# div in label will not check off checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

Is it possible with this HTML to have the DIV tag not check off the input checkbox tag when the DIV tag is clicked on? Is there any CSS that I can add to make this possible?

```
<style>
#myId ~ label {
    position: fixed;
     overflow: auto;

     top: 0;
     left: 0;

    height: 100%;
     width: 100%;



    background-color: red;
}

#myId ~ label div {
    width: 100%;

    background-color: yellow;

    height: 25%;
}

#myId:checked ~ label {
    display: none;
}
</style> 

<input id="myId" type="checkbox" />
<label for="myId">
    <div>Hello</div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the `<label>` element that's causing the issue; HTML is wired such that when you specify the `for` attribute on the label, it ties it to the `<input>` element with the matching `name` or `id` attribute. So when you click on the *label*, the checkbox changes. This is the default browser functionality. You could remove the `<label>` element from around the `<div>`, or if you want to use some css, you can do:

#### Option 1

```
label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Option 2

Or if you don't want to override the click functionality of all labels, you can do:

```
label > div {
  pointer-events: none !important; /* disable from div */
}
label {
  pointer-events: auto; /* enable only on label */
}
```

#### Option 3

If you want to target *just* that label, you can do:

```
label[for=myId] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### Option 4

Or

```
label[for=myId] > div {
  pointer-events: none !important; /* disable for div */
}
label[for=myId] {
  pointer-events: auto; /* enable for label */
}
```

---

#### Option 5 (JavaScript)

If you still want to be able to click your event but prevent click events from bubbling up to the parent label, that is called "stop propagation" and unfortunately there is no direct CSS approach; you'd have to use some JavaScript. Here's an example. [Documentation for event.stopPropagation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp)

```
<body>
  <input id='myId' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='myId'>
    <div id='label-div'>Hello</div>
  </label>

  <script>
    var label = document.getElementById('label-div');
    label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

```css
label {
  pointer-events: auto;
  
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
label > div {
  pointer-events: none !important;
  
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='myId' />
<label for='myId'>
  <div>Hello</div>
</label>
```

```css
#unclickable {
  pointer-events: none !important;
 
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  pointer-events: all;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='myId' />
<div id='unclickable'>
  <label for='myId'>Hello</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to click on the label tag but I do not want to click the label tag when I click on the div tag. the pointer-events will disable the click functionality on the label and the div tag. Is there a way to disable the div tag but enable the label tag for activating the checkox when clicked?

Comment: Yes, but not with css that I know of. I've updated the answer with information about how to use javascript. See Option 5.

Comment: I am trying to do this with CSS only so this can work on browsers that disable javascript.

Comment: Can you please expand on your use case a bit? Are you doing this for work, personal, or school? Is it actually likely that people with javascript disabled are going to be using what you are creating? That's a very, very small percentage of people. https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/stats-no-javascript.html

Comment: Even if you found a css-only way of doing this, it's not always a guarantee that all browsers support it. Here's information about what browsers implement the `pointer-events` property, for example: https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're looking for now. I've updated options 2 and 4...try those. You basically disable pointer-events for the `div` but reenable for the `label`.

Comment: I tried 2 and 4 and it did not work. The pointer-events will either disable clicking on the label and div or allow clicking on both the label and the div. Are there any other CSS tricks that can make this work?

Comment: I don't think so. The label contains the div, so when you click the div, the DOM handles that as a click to the label first and then to the div. Can you swap the label as a child of the div instead? I added a snippet showing how this could work. I really need to understand more of what you're going for, why does the div exist? Does it have some special styling? Any chance you could post a screenshot?

Comment: I am trying to make a simple modal using CSS only. I want the modal to have a background that will dim the screen and when you click the background, it will close the modal. Then I want to have a DIV inside the label which is the modal itself and you can click on the DIV which is the modal and it will not close the modal.